# Iron Router dynamic routes don't re-render

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have a route that looks like this:

```
@.route 'dailyTotal',
    path: '/report/:year/:month/:day'
    template: 'dailyTotal'
    layoutTemplate: 'report'
    data: ()-> this.params
```

And in my controller something like this:

```
Template.dailyTotal.bevTable = ->
  params = this
  # a whole bunch more...
```

In the controller, I use those params to do some rather complicated stuff that isnt' relevant to my question because this doesn't re-render (or execute?) when you navigate from one dynamic route to another.

For example, if I navigate from "/report/2014/05/21" to "/report/2014/05/22" nothing happens. That route only executes if you come from a completely different route (say, "/report/totals" for example).

When I put a break point in the controller it never gets this, but I see the params change within the data function. My gut tells me I need to somehow force the controller action to run, but it isn't obvious from either the IronRouter or Meteor docs. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your issue by creating simple meteor app with route you published above, but no luck, IronRouter properly handles this case.
Please compare your code with :
https://github.com/parhelium/meteo-so-ironrouter-dynamic-routes

IronRouter properly detects change of params in the same route, so going first to **/report/2014/05/21** and then to **/report/2014/05/21** re-renders template properly.

App structure was generated using [em](https://github.com/EventedMind/em) tool, it generated a lot of dirs and files, but only few are important in this situation:

```
both/router/routes.js
client/controllers/report.js
client/views/report/*
```

### Update

When you pass `this.params` through `data` field in controller then usage in template for your route is:

```
{{year}}/{{month}}/{{day}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have some differences, so I tried an experiment to make my code and structure match yours.

Comment: Gah. The solution to my problem was just to set a Session var in the data() hook. So silly of me to overlook....

Comment: @jasongonzales: I am experiencing the same issue you did. Could you elaborate on how setting a session var in the data() hook solved the issue? Thanks!

Comment: Owen, this may not apply to what you're doing, but feel free to have a look in my repo: https://github.com/jasongonzales23/inventoryapp. I don't remember the details because I wrote this fast, and it's been a while, but it looks like I just set a session var to get the data I needed via the data() hook.